# Is there any way to import a folder containing Qml files, which is outside of project directory?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a set of Qmls which are available in a folder. Now I want to use these Qml files in a Qt project. Is there any way to import those QMLs in my project without copying the Qml folder to my project directory?

My .pro file looks like this:

```
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
RESOURCES += $$PWD/../QML_Assets


QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/../QML_Assets
QML2_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/../QML_Assets
```

The immediate qrc generates like this :

D:/Qt_Projects/Dummy_sample/QML_Assets/QML_2.qml
D:/Qt_Projects/Dummy_sample/QML_Assets/QML_1.qml

If i add import "../QML_Assets/" then my application starts & exits immediatly.
If I dont import this & comment the components which are used from QML_Assets folder then it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is are couple of possibilities to do that in Qt.

First you can set variables in your Qt project file (.pro) to add QML imports paths.

```
# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML2_IMPORT_PATH =
```

You can also do that directly in c++ code with [QQmlEngine::addImportPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) before constructing/starting your Qml view

You can then check wich import paths are set for your app with [QQmlEngine::importPathList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#importPathList)

Here is Qt documentation about [Import Statements](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path) and [QML Import Path](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path) specifically

And even more specific: [Importing QML Document Directories](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html)

Comment: Could you please share a link with example which uses  
QML_IMPORT_PATH = " ....."
QML2_IMPORT_PATH = "...." 

in .pro file?

Comment: It is a simple path to your folder. You could find example in Qt Demos/Examples. For example here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdoc-demos-coffee-example.html look in coffee.pro file

Comment: What you are saying is correct but in coffee example , all the resources are added to qrc file. But when I moved the import folder 1 level up then it could not detect that, even I have put   QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/../imports   , instead of QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/imports.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about QML Import paths and not about qml files import to the qrc file? Have you read about directory imports -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html

Comment: Yes I read about same, but when i do in that way my application can access the qmls but it then exited with code -1.

Comment: And what does the debugger says? If you could post example of your case this could help

Comment: I updated the question..

Is there any way we can add entries in qrc file? like how we add in SOURCES + = main.cpp ,   similarly qml.qrc + = file1.qml .